# how to write a small calculator in C++ language?

Tags: c++, calculator

how can i Write a small calculator that takes as input one of the four arithmetic operations, the two arguments to those operations, and then prints out the result?
just as simple as that, i don't need a real calculator.

here is what i tried so far, but well it didn't work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int  x,y,result;
  string arithmatic;
  cout<<"enter the first number:";
  cin>>x;
  cout<<"enter the second number:";
  cin>>y;
  cout<<"use one of the four artimatic operations /, *, + or - :";
  cin>>arithmatic;
  if (arithmatic=="/" )
    result=x/y;
  cout<<"x / y ="<<result;
  if  (arithmatic == "*")
    result=x*y;
  cout<<"x * y ="<<result;
  if (arithmatic == "+")
    result = x + y;
  cout<<"x+y ="<<result;
  if (arithmatic == "-")
    result = x-y;
  cout<<"x-y ="<<result;
  else
  cout<<"what is this? i said use arithmatic operations!";

  return 0;
}
```

i know there is a lot wrong with this program, i just started learning out, and this practice was in a book.

Comment: Show the code that you've written so far.

Comment: You want to learn how to write a small calculator that performs `+, -, *, /` but you don't want a real calculator...sorry...just sayin...

Comment: Open a text editor and start coding ...

Comment: Sounds like someone want's us to write their homework :)

Comment: Could you provide more information on the desired input format (eg. do you want spaces to be allowed, what order do you want operations in, what type of operations you want (integer or double division), etc.)?

Comment: If you ask a SPECIFIC question as to how to solve a particular part of the problem, you'll get much better response than "I have a plan to write some program, what do I do?"

Comment: i actually did write something, i will add it to my question.

Comment: what's with the minus points everytime...

Comment: I suspect the minus points are for not showing the code. I just gave the question an upvote, now that it has code.

Comment: You need some braces for your if statements. Also, you should use else ifs, otherwise your else will print anytime you don't use subtraction.

Comment: copy this code and submit it as yours: http://www.mpgh.net/forum/31-c-c-programming/402554-very-simple-c-calculator.html

Comment: @thang That code also misses some braces (see else statement at the end...) ;)

Comment: @leemes, to tell you the truth, I didn't really look at it, so you may very well be right :p  I just googled something to the point of small c++ calculator, and that's one of the first few links.

Comment: @AmirRazoR "but well it didn't work" You know what is wrong (what you were expecting to see, and what you actually saw), but you didn't tell us. If you don't tell us what you think is wrong, then it makes it harder for us to help.

Comment: now that i improved my question by adding the code, i request to upvote the downvotes, because of this my account is banned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple issues:

- You're missing a lot of braces between your `if` statements. This results in `std::cout` being called numerous times throughout the code.
- You're using a lot of `if` statements that is terminated by a single `else`, use `if` `else if` `else` instead.
- You're using integer division rather than floating point division. If you want an "accurate" result use floats instead.

Answer (score 2):

You always write the result to the console, if this is the requested operation or not.

```
if (arithmatic =="/")
    result=x/y;
cout<<"x / y ="<<result;
if (arithmatic == "*")
    result=x*y;
cout<<"x * y ="<<result;
...
```

It should be:

```
if (arithmatic =="/") {
    result=x/y;
    cout<<"x / y ="<<result;
}
if (arithmatic == "*") {
    result=x*y;
    cout<<"x * y ="<<result;
}
...
```

Also, since the cases are exclusive, you should rather use `else if` in consecutive blocks. Another options is to use `switch (...) { case ... }`, which however operates on integral values like a single character. Take the first character of the string to apply this method:

```
switch (arithmatic.at(0)) {
    case '/':
        result = x / y;
        break;
    case '*':
        result = x * y;
        break;
    case '+':
        result = x + y;
        break;
    case '-':
        result = x - y;
        break;
    default:
        cout << "what is this? i said use arithmatic operations!" << endl;
        exit(1); // abort execution
}
cout << "x " << arithmatic << " y = " << result << endl;
```

Also, you should consider that you're currently operating on integers only. Not only the input can't be any decimal, but also you're doing *integer division*, which results in an integer even if it has to be rounded (in this case, it is rounded down). To solve this, use the `double` type instead of `int` for the operands for a good accuracy (about 17 meaningful decimal digits are possible with `double`).

Please note that you spelled *arithmetic* wrong. I used your wrong spelling in the code above.

Answer (score 1):

That `else` is just dangling at the end. It has to go with an `if` statement. The usual way of writing that kind of thing is

```
if (first)
  do_first();
else if (second)
  do_second();
else if (third)
  do_third();
else
  do_everything_else();
```

Now the exercise for you is to combine this structure with the braces that @leemes showed you.